# Gridview BoundField Editing Textbox Enable Multiline

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I don't know if its possible to display a fixed textbox with multiline, when clicking edit link in gridview.

Codes:

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="AboutUs_Text" HeaderText="About Us Editor" ItemStyle-CssClass="editing" >
                <ControlStyle Width="100%" />
                <ControlStyle height="100px" />
            </asp:Boundfield>

  protected void gvAboutUs_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
```

aspx.cs
    {

```
    gvAboutUs.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
    bind();
}
```

[LINK TO PICTURE OF TEXTBOX](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Wzu8.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can be done with a TemplateField:

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("AboutUs_Text") %>' ... />
    </ItemTemplate>
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" Rows="4" TextMode="MultiLine" Text='<%# Eval("AboutUs_Text") %>' ... />
    </EditItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: It's necessary to use Bind() instead of Eval() on the TextBox to have the Edit Update save the changes made by the user.

Comment: this worked for me with minor tweaks. thank you for this!     <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="Comments" HeaderStyle-Width="130px">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Comments") %>' />
                    </ItemTemplate>

                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox runat="server" Rows="4" TextMode="MultiLine" Text='<%# Eval("Comments") %>' />
                    </EditItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateColumn>